# Constructor issues with django models multiple inheritance

Tags: django, django-models

In my django app's models.py, I inherit from two classes: models.Model and a class called Isbn10 from an imported Python module pyisbn. However, if I try to create an instance of the class, I get a TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

I've tried reversing the parent class order, but it didn't help.

Model:

```
from django.db import models
import pyisbn

class Book10(pyisbn.Isbn10, models.Model):
    pass
```

Isbn Class definition (defined in pyisbn module):

```
class Isbn(object):
     def __init__(self, isbn):
        super(Isbn, self).__init__()
        self._isbn = isbn
        if len(isbn) in (9, 12):
            self.isbn = _isbn_cleanse(isbn, False)
        else:
            self.isbn = _isbn_cleanse(isbn)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your **init**() definition requires both a self and a Isbn. So you'd have to pass both. Also, self should always be the first argument.

Comment: Do you mean that I need Isbn(self, '9780887276309') to create a new instance? It doesn't work. Note that the Isbn class is defined in pyisbn which is a third-party python module not specific to django.